# Schedule Facebook posts for scheduled WordPress post? (preview breaks currently)

Tags: facebook, wordpress, scheduling

You can schedule WordPress posts which is awesome. However, I also want to schedule the Facebook post to post at the same time. The issue is Facebook goes out and pulls in the title description when you write the post, even if it is scheduled in the future. So to Facebook, the WordPress post doesn't exist yet and when it is published, it shows up like this:

[image: Page not found]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @serenesat If you schedule a non-published post the title and content preview are broken. How do you avoid this.